# Fetching photos in the favourites on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I use `PictureAlbum` API to get those photos in favorite folder of photo gallery, but there is nothing, how can I get them?

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

According to [**MediaLibrary Favorite Pictures Bug?**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/b57da1aa-cbe6-471b-be4c-6fe96a99c353) it seems like favorites album is always empty, there is a bug report on this issue. Below code will yield zero pictures for favorites even if you have pics in your favorites.

---

Something like this:

```cs
using (var library = new MediaLibrary()) {
    var allAlbums = library.RootPictureAlbum.Albums;
    var favAlbum = allAlbums
          .Where(album => album.Name == "Favorite Pictures")
          .FirstOrDefault();

    if (favAlbum != null) {
      var favPics = favAlbum.Pictures;
      ...
    }
}
```

Note for this to work you need to add ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO to your app capabilities.